# javascript not outputting value

Tags: javascript

I made a super simple website a few years ago and haven't used JS since.  Went to add a new calculate form and it isn't outputting any values.
If I enter a number then hit the Calculate button it does nothing.
Please help.

```js
function updateOutput7() {
  //get form
  var form = document.getElementById("calc7");
  //get number
  var num1 = parseInt(form.elements["x"].value);
  //multiply 2;
  var num2 = 2;
  //add 69
  var num3 = 69;
  //amount1
  var amount1;
  //get output
  var out = form.elements["z"];

  //Calculate
  amount1 = num1 * num2 + num3;

  //pick the larger variable
  out.value = amount1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calc7" onsubmit="updateOutput7(); return false;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Part Cost</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Charge</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" name="x">
      </td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td>$
        <output name="z"></output>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" onclick="updateOutput7();">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: how are you attaching the script to your HTML?

Comment: Your code works for me as well.

Comment: Are you executing your jQuery before the DOM is ready? Move your jQuery to the end of the page or wrap it in a document ready call.

Comment: the snippet was updated and that fixed it. The function did not have a closing bracket and i believe needed a semi-colon

Comment: Dennington make your post an answer and I'll mark it.  Thanks guys! I was missing a stupid bracket at the end *exasperation*

Comment: There's no answer needed for that as any question where the solution is a simple typo is off-topic and should be closed.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Is this something I need to do? Do I delete this post.  Still new.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function updateOutput7() {
            //get form
            var txtb = document.getElementById("txt");
            //get number
            var num1 = parseInt(txtb.value);
            if (isNaN(num1)) {
                document.getElementById("z").innerText = "Invalid Number"
                return;
            }
            //multiply 2;
            var num2 = 2;
            //add 69
            var num3 = 69;
            //amount1
            var amount1;
            //get output


            //Calculate
            amount1 = num1 * num2 + num3;

            //pick the larger variable
            document.getElementById("z").innerText = amount1;
        }
    </script>
    <form id="calc7" onsubmit="updateOutput7(); return false;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Part Cost</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Charge</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="txt" type="text" name="x">
                </td>
                <td>=</td>
                <td>
                    $
                    <span id="z"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="updateOutput7();">Calculate</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: @Dennington-bear was correct, I forgot to close my function.  As he was the one that pointed this out to me, I don't feel I should mark your answer.